How do I overload a certain operator in haskell to take different types on either side?
MRE:
class Foo s where
    myCons :: Char -> s -> s
    myCons c xs = <my definition of however I wish to interpret this>

instance (Eq, Show) Foo where
    (:) x y = x `myCons` y

Error:
Pattern bindings (except simple variables) not allowed in instance declaration:
      (:) x y = x `myCons` y

What am I doing wrong?
What I want to do:
fooFromList :: [Int] -> Foo
fooFromList [] = Foo []
fooFromList (x:xs) = let x' = (convertDigitToChar x) in x':(fooFromList xs)


instance (Eq, Show) Foo where?

It is not clear what you are trying to do...

@willeM_VanOnsem I'm basically trying to overload : to work on my own datatype

But you also seem to use class here as data. class in Haskell is a typeclass, and acts more like what in Java would be an "interface".

I'm not really sure about what I've written as this is my first time delving into the type classes in haskell... :( I don't really understand the construct very well. So if I am trying to make Foo an instance of Eq and Show, how would I do that?

: is not a member of a typeclass, and therefore cannot be "overloaded."  Eq and Show define the functions == and show, which you can define as you like for foo, but that doesn't mean you can change :.

You can do this with a new function not named :, however.

I recommend simply extracting the Foo application outside of the recursion. (In fact... is a new type really needed, or have you just made it as a guess? What does Foo do that [Char] doesn't?)
fooFromList :: [Int] -> Foo
fooFromList xs = Foo (map convertDigitToChar xs)


So if I am trying to make Foo an instance of Eq and Show, how would I do that?

The compiler can write those instances for you, and it's rare to do something different than what the deriver does.
data Foo = Foo [Char] deriving (Eq, Show)


You can not override existing functions. Haskell uses ad-hoc polymorphism for this.
What you can however do in the case of a list, is work with the OverloadedLists extension [ghc-doc].
If you thus have a data type Foo with:
data Foo a = MyEmpty | MyCons a (Foo a)
You can use:
import GHC.IsList (IsList)

instance IsList (Foo a) where
  type Item (Foo a) = a
  toList = foldr MyCons MyEmpty
  fromList MyEmpty = []
  fromList (MyCons x xs) = x : fromList xs
If you then compile with -XOverloadedLists, you can use list literals in your code that are then of type Foo a.
But this does not overload the (:) function: if you use :, it will still use the (:) :: a -> [a] -> [a] one.

um... yeah, something this complicated is not expected in the assignment. I think I'm going down a rabbit hole here
